# What does "run the mirror down" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, translation, french

In Richard Philcox's translation of Frantz Fanon's *Black Skin, White Masks*, he includes the following sentence:

> I try to read admiration in the eyes of the other, and if, as luck would have it, the other sends back an unpleasant reflection, I *run the mirror down*: the other is a real idiot.  (Italics mine)

What does to "run the mirror down" mean?  I've never heard this phrase before.  Is it an unfortunate translation of a French idiom?

I assume that the "run" in this case is used in the sense of running a flag up or down a flagpole, but then why is he running the mirror *down*?  Isn't he bringing the mirror to bear, i.e. running it *up* the flagpole of his body?

Comment: [run sb/sth down](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-sb-sth-down): (informal) to criticize someone or something, often unfairly: *He's always running himself down.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it assumes that 'run the mirror down' is an idiom, rather than this being an offbeat example of 'run somebody/something down', which is not suitable for ELU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Run down* is a (fairly colloquial) idiom meaning "criticize" or "deprecate the value of"--the verb in the original French is *dévaloriser*. The "mirror" here is the eyes of the other, thus the other himself. Since he fails so badly to 'reflect' my self-admiration, he can't be worth much: he's a real idiot.